updating few fields of ant design form by using react query. Then update page using queryclient.invalidateQuesries. Page loose focus
I update few fields of a form using ant design using & onFinish= {onFinish}
    const onFinish = (values) => {
//pass the field to mutate destructured from useMutation      
mutate(values)    
 }

using useMutation from React Query with axios to interact with server.
    const {mutate, isLoading} = useMutate('updatedData', {
onSuccess:() => {queryClient.invalidateQueries()}, 
onError: .... })

Calling invalidateQueries, to update page so that I can see the changes UI instantly.
Now issue is, it take the page to the inital state, so if I have made changes to some column then again I have to click on that column to see the changes.
I want to acheive that I stay on the same state and I dont have to click again to some column to see the UI Changes.

To keep the focus on the form after updating with React Query and prevent the page from resetting to the initial state, you can try the following approach:

Avoid invalidateQueries if it's not necessary. Instead, you can
update the React Query cache directly in the onSuccess callback,
which will avoid refetching data and preserve the page state.


   const { mutate, isLoading } = useMutation(updateData, {
      onSuccess: (updatedValues) => {
        queryClient.setQueryData('updatedData', (oldData) => ({
          ...oldData,
          ...updatedValues, // merge updated fields with the existing 
            data
        }));
      },
      onError: (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      },
    })



Use invalidateQueries selectively: If you need to re-fetch only part
of the data, consider invalidating a specific part of the cache
rather than the entire query.

Restore Focus: If the focus still resets, manually set focus on the
affected field after mutation by selecting it with
document.getElementById or using refs.


This should help you update data without losing focus or resetting the form state.
